# Do I want normalized line endings?

Tags: visual-studio, line-endings

I am getting the following message in Visual Studio 2008:

> The line endings in the following file
>   are not consistent. Do you want to
>   normalize the line endings?

I don't understand what that means. Should I be clicking yes or no?

[image]

Comment: Do you use version control?  If so, which?  Also, what type is your file and what do you use it for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Visual Studio mean by normalize inconsistent line endings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553548/what-does-visual-studio-mean-by-normalize-inconsistent-line-endings)

Comment: I'm not using a version control tool. It is an aspx.vb file. I'm using visual studio 2008.

Comment: @Matt. Thanks, that's a useful link. Doesn't say whether to click "yes" or "no" though. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Urby: it really doesn't matter until someone opens the file on another platform (*nix, Mac). You might as well click yes.

Comment: Here's a little context to understand exactly why VS is asking you thing in the first place: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_ending

Comment: Cool, that's what I wanted to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The correct answer is almost always "Yes" and "Windows (CR LF)".  The reason is that line endings in source files should almost always be consistent within the file and source files on Windows should generally have CR LF endings.  There are exceptions but if if they applied to you, you would probably know about them.  The warning is a good one because it informs you that somehow the file got into this inconsistent state and because it gives you a choice for how to handle the situation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll choose "yes" from now on then.

Comment: When using a source control system that is NOT Windows-based, it may be forcing the line-endings to be other than CR/LF. This is not unusual.  Personally, since SSMS can handle either ending, I'm not sure why it bothers to inform anyone.  It only matters if one uses an editor that can't recognize non CR/LF endings.