# Dotless Parse doesn't minify carriage returns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, less, dotless

I got the old [Would you like to normalize line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553548/what-does-visual-studio-mean-by-normalize-inconsistent-line-endings) on my .less file and without thinking did so.

I realized later that my css wasnt completely minified. Here's the process method for the transform

```
public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
{
    response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
    response.ContentType = "text/css";
}
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Less/css", new LessTransform(), new CssMinify())
    .Include("~/Content/css/App.less"));
```

I put a break point in `Process` and copied the before/after CSS and found that `dotless` was only removing `/r` and not `/n`

Here's a snippet of my css file showing the behavior

**Before dotless Parse**

```
"/*\r\n\r\nApp.less\r\n
```

**After dotless Parse**

```
"/*\n\nApp.less\n
```

So it's technically working, just not optimally. I was thinking about going back and removing the `/r/n` from the file and replacing them with just `/r` but would love a solution that doesn't cause the line endings dialog to pester me whenever I open the file.

**UPDATE:** Forgot that I upgraded the dotless nuget package recently as well

**My Webconfig**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dotless" type="dotless.Core.configuration.DotlessConfigurationSectionHandler, dotless.Core" />
    ...
</configSections>
...
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler, dotless.Core" />
</httpHandlers>
...
<handlers>
     <add name="dotless" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
</handlers>
...
<dotless minifyCss="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that gives me a properly minified result, very similar to what you currently have:

**BundleConfig**

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; // I think is what's missing

var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/Content/css")
    .Include("~/Content/site.less");

cssBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
cssBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());

bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

**LessTransform**

```
public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
{
    response.Content = dotless.Core.Less.Parse(response.Content);
    response.ContentType = "text/css";
}
```

With no **Web.config** sections.

Comment: You can see in my question that my file *was* being minified. The characters being excluded from minification were carriage returns.

Comment: Right, the above code collapses bot \n and \r for me.

Comment: My suggestion would be to remove all the Web.config sections as you shouldn't need both the LessTransform and the dotless handler; change your bundle to a StyleBundle, the LessTransform will handle the transform itself and CssMinify handle the standard minification.