# console application runtime problems

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with my console application. I'm following some kind of a tutorial on networking, and when I try to run in debug I have a weird runtime error I have never seen before.

When I put a breakpoint on the first new line inside the main function and go through the code with Step Over (F10), visual studio executes the first ~3 lines of code including WSAStartup(), then suddenly reaches acomment section:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#include <iostream>

#include "wsh_includes.h"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
//You have to make a call to WSAStartup() before doing anything else with the sockets library

    //WSADATA wsaData; // if this doesn't work
    WSAData wsaData; // then try this instead
    wsh::errcheck(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData), "WSAStartup failed");

    //----------
    //You also have to tell your compiler to link in the Winsock library, usually called
    //wsock32.lib or winsock32.lib, or ws2_32.lib for Winsock 2.0
    //----------
    //you can't use close() to close a socket—you need to use closesocket()
    //----------
    //select() only works with socket descriptors, not file descriptors (like 0 for stdin).
    //There is also a socket class that you can use, CSocket
    //----------

    int status;
    addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    char ipstr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); //make sure it's empty
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; // AF_INET or AF_INET6 to force version
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; //TCP stream sockets

    status = getaddrinfo("www.example.net", NULL, &hints, &res);
    wsh::errcheck(status, "getaddrinfo failed");

    //servinfo now points to a linked list of 1 or more struct addrinfos
    //... do everything until you don't need servinfo anymore ...

    printf("IP addresses for %s:\n\n", argv[1]);

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        void* addr;
        char* ipver;

        //get the pointer to the address itself
        //different fields in IPv4 and IPv6:
        if (p->ai_family == AF_INET) {
            sockaddr_in* ipv4 = (sockaddr_in*)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv4->sin_addr);
            ipver = "IPv4";
        }
        else {
            sockaddr_in6* ipv6 = (sockaddr_in6*)p->ai_addr;
            addr = &(ipv6->sin6_addr);
            ipver = "IPv6";
        }

        //convert the IP to a string and print it:
        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, addr, ipstr, sizeof(ipstr));
        printf("  %s: %s\n", ipver, ipstr);
    }

    std::cin.get();

    freeaddrinfo(res); //free the linked list

//----------
//Finally, you need to call WSACleanup() when you're all through with the sockets library.
    wsh::errcheck(WSACleanup(), "WSACleanup failed");
    return 0;
}
```

When it gets there, it suddenly moves to the file crtexe.c in the middle of the commented section.
More specifically, it jumps to:

```
#ifdef WPRFLAG
            __winitenv = envp;
            mainret = wmain(argc, argv, envp);
#else  /* WPRFLAG */
            __initenv = envp;
            mainret = main(argc, argv, envp); //here
```

then to:

```
#else  /* !defined (_WINMAIN_) && defined (_CRT_APP) */
            if ( !managedapp )
            {
#ifndef _CRT_APP
                exit(mainret); //here
```

I have tried getting rid of all the comments, when I run in debug then the code will behave differently (yet not really as expected).

What exactly is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Right-click the source file and find the menu item that has to do with normalizing line endings. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553548/what-does-visual-studio-mean-by-normalize-inconsistent-line-endings/553560#553560) for info on what that means. The issue usually happens when the IDE can't match the execution point with the source code due to mismatched line endings.

Comment: @KenWhite Where do I find that menu item or how is it called exactly? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @KenWhite I found it in advanced save options. Thanks for the help, it works now.

Comment: You found it quicker than I could see your comment and open VS. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by mismatched line endings (some lines ending with a CR/LF, some ending with just a CR or LF), which causes the IDE not to be able to keep the code editor and debugger in synch.

VS often recognizes this condition and displays a dialog asking about whether you want to normalize line endings (see [What does Visual Studio mean by normalizing line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553548/what-does-visual-studio-mean-by-normalize-inconsistent-line-endings) for more information).

You can fix this yourself by using the **File->Advanced Save Options** menu item, and setting the **Line Endings** to **Windows (CR LF)**.