# Visual Studio Call Stack - Wrong line highlighted in Source Code window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My System:  Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, VB.Net

My Problem:
Often, but not always, when I double-click on a line in my Call Stack window, it takes me to (and highlights) the wrong line of source code in my Source Code window.

Notes:

- My solution is fairly large:  Dozens of projects.
- No one else on my team has ever gotten my problem.  They all get the same source from the same source control.  Their systems are same as mine:  W7, VS2012, VB.Net.

What I've tried already (but hasn't worked):

- Restarted Visual Studio / Rebooted computer.
- Clean Solution (from Build menu).
- Rebuild Solution (from Build menu).
- Deleted all my source code (entire solution folder, including .sln, .suo, .vbproj files, etc) from my local computer and re-gotten all
  the source code from source control.
- Used inappropriate language.

I think that my problem is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748760/vb-net-call-stack-in-microsoft-visual-studio-wrong-line-of-source-highlighted)

What is the solution?

Comment: If a question has no accepted answer, then it is not a problem to ask it again. @JohnStossel256

Comment: @manetsus:  Thank you for tip, and for edit :-)

Comment: I also tried resetting my Visual Studio settings.  It did not work either.    Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings > ... > Visual Basic Development Settings > [Finish]