# Flyway Error - When I run migrate command. I get "Unable to calculate checksum"

Tags: sql-server, docker, flyway

I'm running this command

```
 docker run --network=foo --rm -v C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/flyway/sql:/flyway/sql flyway/flyway migrate -user=sa -password=MyPassword001 -url="jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver-test:1433;databaseName=master"
```

And I've got this error.

```
Flyway Community Edition 6.0.1 by Boxfuse
Database: jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver-test:1433;useBulkCopyForBatchInsert=false;cancelQueryTimeout=-1;sslProtocol=TLS;jaasConfigurationName=SQLJDBCDriver;statementPoolingCacheSize=0;serverPreparedStatementDiscardThreshold=10;enablePrepareOnFirstPreparedStatementCall=false;fips=false;socketTimeout=0;authentication=NotSpecified;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustStoreType=JKS;trustServerCertificate=false;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true;serverNameAsACE=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;queryTimeout=-1;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=master;columnEncryptionSetting=Disabled;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite; (Microsoft SQL Server 14.0)
ERROR: Unable to calculate checksum for V1.1__My_description.sql: Input length = 1
```

The file's content is very simple. I create a table.

I'm using Flyway Community Edition 6.0.1 by Boxfuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, The problem was in the line endings. My file had inconsistent Line endings. some lines ends with `\r\n` and another ending with `\r` or `\n`. This hapend because I generated a sql script since SQL Management Studio.
[normalize inconsistent line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553548/what-does-visual-studio-mean-by-normalize-inconsistent-line-endings)
The solution was in SQL Management Studio too.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case I had to change the sql file encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 to avoid this error.

I did this by opening the sql file in Notepad++. After clicking "Convert to UTF-8" from the "Encoding" menu I saved the file and reran the flyway command with success.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue.
I just created a normal text file. opened it in notepad and pasted the whole SQL script.
[image]

then renamed it to SQL file (ex: filename.sql)
After that, I tried to run it through the flyway and it worked.