# How to avoid mixed eol-styles in a svn repository

Tags: svn, line-endings, newline, eol

Is there a best practice for preventing mixed eol-styles in a subversion repository.

I know that `svn:eol-style=native` can be set as an auto-prop, but I would have to ensure that it was set for all committers. I'm also reluctant to do a retrospective, repository-wide change of `svn:eol-style` if there is a less invasive solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use pre-commit hooks on server-side.

Here is a hook you need: 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/check-mime-type.pl

This hook will enforce users to set correct eol-style.

See [svn documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/svn-book.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1) on how to use them.

Also, you can implement your own hook which will set eol-style automatically.

Comment: Thanks uthark - I suspected that hooks were the answer. I'd hoped for something else since the repository isn't hosted by me but at least I'm off in the right direction

Answer (score 6):

Note that as of SVN 1.8 you can set up **auto-props** for entire trees within your repository (including at the top level), which finally fixes this issue *independent of client-side config*.

See the following for more details:

- The [relevant part](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#iprops) of the [SVN 1.8 release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html)
- [The entry on auto properties in svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) (I'd advise you read about inheritable properties too, which is in the section immediately above)
- [A useful article on Apache's wiki about the subject](http://wiki.apache.org/subversion/Inheritable-Ignores-AutoProps), complete with examples for eol-style

Comment: You should specify the URL to svnbook chapter about new autoprops and svn 1.8 release notes as well.

Comment: Although I somewhat assume people can use $SEARCH_ENGINE, you are right. Fixed to be more comprehensive.