# removing ^M characters that is safe for svn

Tags: svn

I have a file with a bunch of ^M characters at the end of every line in svn.

When I run dos2unix on the file, it removes the ^M characters, but svn still sees the file as having every line different.

Is there a way to fix the file w/o causing svn to see it as different on every line?

Comment: You probably want to configure SVN to handle this for you itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687/how-can-i-convert-all-line-endings-to-crlf-lf-or-cr-during-svn-operations

Comment: You can set the `eol-style` property to `native`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone's editor is finding one ^M and then assuming the entire file should be that way and converting them. I just ran dos2unix and used this command to see the real diff.

```
dos2unix filename.php
svn diff --diff-cmd diff -x -uw filename.php
```